# Get current url using javascript, and see if string exists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a reliable way to get the current URL in the browser using javascript, and to test whether a string is contained in the url.

Is this a safe process between all the browsers?

Comment: define safe? Why wouldnt it be safe to load a url in javascript?

Comment: @mark - OP is asking if this is x-browser compatible.

Comment: i recall that some array indexing or something doesn't work in IE but does in firefox.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) against the [`window.location.href`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CBcQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fwindow.location&ei=0_UhTdPbEoLSsAPlqpivAg&usg=AFQjCNHGtlBZQOYyqIv842TeeFfwyuxHVQ&sig2=ZvTrztBmfG8e0nBZwhS2EA), but be aware that you're testing the entire url.

```
if( window.location.href.indexOf( 'someString' ) != -1 ) {
    alert( 'the string was found' );
}
```

Comment: @Yads: That is simply not true. Perhaps you're thinking of `Array.indexOf()`. This is `String.indexOf()`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
   var s="yourstring";
   if(document.location.href.search(s) != -1)
        document.write("yes");
   else 
        document.write("no");
</script>
```

?

Answer (score 2):

I really like the jQuery URL Parser to work against the URL in JavaScript. It is a great utility to get various parts of the URL and compose new ones.

http://projects.allmarkedup.com/jquery_url_parser/